# Icons doesn't show up with Qt 4.8.6 on Win CE

Tags: qt, svg, icons, action, windows-ce

currently i'm developing an app with qt for a handheld with some kind of win ce 5.0 as os. In my `QMainFrame` inheriting class i've got some actions. Theese actions have icons from the .qrc file. My problem is that theese icons show up if i view the .ui file in qt-creator but they don't show up when running the .exe file on the device no metter if i take a .jpg, .png or .svg as resource. What am i missing?

I'm developing on a win xp sp3 32-bit machine with microsoft visual studio 2005 standard edition. As sdk i'm using the ms standard sdk for win ce 5.0. 
I've installed the qt vs addin v1.1.11. Qt version is 4.8.6 which i build from sources using msvc and configured it with
`-platform win32-msvc2005 -xplatform wince50standard-armv4i-msvc2005 -D QT_NO_DRAGANDDROP -D QT_NO_SESSIONMANAGER -D QT_NO_ACCESSIBILITY -D QT_NO_CURSOR -D QT_NO_CLIPBOARD`
The .qrc file is located in the project's directory and contains the icons
which are located in the project directory too. In the .pro the .qrc file
is included via
`RESOURCES+=mainwindow.qrc`
As modules i use
`QT += core gui`
in the .pro file.

I can see how the icons get transformed into an array in the qrc_mainwindow.cpp. When debugging the .exe with msvc while running on the device there's no message about failures due to theese icons.

Comment: It's going to be hard to figure out your problem without a small example the reproduces the problem. As it stands, this question is a wall of text and acronyms. What steps have you taken to solve this? What were the results?

Comment: It is possible that icon encoding is newer than qt supported, try encoding icon in lower version.

Comment: I solved it! How do i mark this thread as solved and where to post my solution?